# Do native speakers use "whatever" in place of "what"?

Tags: pronouns

I have heard phrases like the following in animations:

> Whatever happened to Naruto?
>
> Oh god, whatever happens now?
>
> Whatever is the matter?

Why **what** is being replaced by **whatever** in these phrases?

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about the difference between these two words?

Comment: I think in practice, native speakers see "what" and "whatever" as largely interchangeable with "whatever" being a more fanciful option. Really, "whatever" is more of an expression of surprise whereas "what" is more emotionally flat. I picture "what is the matter" as a question being asked by an emotionless policeman while "whatever is the matter" is more like the the same question from your dear old grandmother, who possibly offers you a cookie.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh You have asked many questions, so by now you know it helps us to answer if you tell us what research you have done on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is synonymous with "what" when it is used in a question. It is an intensifier: e[xpressing surprise or confusion](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20whatever).

For example "What do you mean?"
in a neutral question. Whereas "Whatever do you mean?"
Implies that I think you are talking nonsense.

"Whatever happened to Naruto?" implies that the speaker was expecting to know what had happened, and was surprised.

In this use, "Whatever" is a pronoun, and not an adverb.